# Unable to set desired icon in dialog box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I want to set an icon on the picture control of my dialog box. I created a Control variable for my picture control and I tried setting the icon using *loadimage* and *seticon* funcitons as below.

```
CStatic pic_var;
HANDLE icon= LoadImage(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1),IMAGE_ICON,0,0,LR_DEFAULTCOLOR|LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
pic_var.SetIcon((HICON)icon);
```

But my `LoadImage` fails. The error code returned was

```
"ERROR CODE: 1813 ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND
The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file."
```

I tried with `LoadIcon`, but nothing changed. Can any one spot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you load the picture into your resource folder and assign a resource ID?

Comment: From my resource.rc file, i did Add_resource->icon->import and added the .ico files. I did assigned resource ID, IDI_ICON1 for the icon i have loaded.

Comment: why are you giving NULL as first parameter in the loadImage? should it be `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` ? Can you try this?

Comment: GetModuleHandle(NULL) solved it . Thank you very much.